# pass id with jquery load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i have this following jquery to load partial view in a div

```
 var acc = this.id;    
$('#details').load('/AccountAndTransaction/Grab', function (html)
            { $('#details')[0].value = html; });
```

and its working good , but now i want to pass 'var acc' with this load method ,  how can i achiev this??

controlller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Grab(string AccountNumber)
    {

        TermDepositAccountViewModel tdParent = new TermDepositAccountViewModel();
        account ac = db.accounts.Single(u => u.accountNumber == AccountNumber);
        deposittd td = db.deposittds.Single(u => u.accountNumber == AccountNumber);
        tdParent.deposittd = td;
        tdParent.account = ac;
        return PartialView("TermDepositPartialView", tdParent);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass the `acc` as part of the URL. Since you have named your parameter in the Action method as `AccountNumber` it should be in this format.

```
$('#details').load('/AccountAndTransaction/Grab?AccountNumber=' + acc, function (html)
```

if your parameter name is `id` you can have it in this format (as in the default route the optional parameter is mapped as `id`, it should be automatically handled)

```
$('#details').load('/AccountAndTransaction/Grab/' + acc, function (html)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     //var AccountNumber=   $(this).attr('id');  // try this

     $('#details').load('/AccountAndTransaction/Grab', {
          AccountNumber:AccountNumber} function (html){   
          $('#details:first').html(data); });
          //Or

          var AccountNumber = $(this).attr('id');
          $.ajax({
                url: '/AccountAndTransaction/Grab', type: 'Get', dataType: 'json',
                data: { AccountNumber: AccountNumber },
                success: function (data) {
                     $('#details:first').html(data);
                }
          });
     }
```

Comment: please , never use `$(this).attr('id')` again.